# Accessing jupyter notebook from anaconda prompt while still using command line

Tags: command-line, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, background-process

I would like to launch my jupyter notebook from Anaconda prompt but still have access to the command line to run other code.

I thought I could do this with

```
jupyter notebook &
```

However, when I do this, the notebook launches correctly, but I do not get access to my command line.

I'm almost positive I've done this successfully when using a linux vm. Is the problem that I'm using anaconda prompt on a windows machine? Or is there some easy workaround that would let me launch jupyter notebooks from the command line, but run it in the background so I can still use my command line for other things?